# Скрипт для поиска и переименования подпапок в каталоге

Tags: python

Как написать скрипт, который ищет в каталоге подпапку с именем `0.1` и переименовывает её, допустим, в `0.2`?

На скриншоте стуктура папок:

[image: Структкра папок]

Comment: С чем у вас возникла проблема?

Comment: Извините, а с копи и паста у вас тоже не получается? Попробуйте - выделить область, нажать клавишу "Enter" (может также "Ввод"), в другом окне - Ctrl+C. Задайте новый вопрос, если не получится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем `pathlib`:

```
try:
    from pathlib import Path       # Python 3.x
except ImportError:
    from pathlib2 import Path      # Python 2.x
```

---

```
In [116]: p = Path(r'C:\Temp\aaa')
```

директория до переименования:

```
In [117]: [x for x in p.glob('**/*')]
Out[117]:
[WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/a'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/b'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/c'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/a/0.1'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/a/test'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/b/0.1'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/b/test'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/c/0.1'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/c/test')]
```

переименование:

```
In [118]: _ = [x.rename(str(x).replace('0.1','0.2'))
               for x in p.glob('**/*') 
               if x.name == '0.1']
```

директория после переименования:

```
In [119]: [x for x in p.glob('**/*')]
Out[119]:
[WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/a'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/b'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/c'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/a/0.2'),  # <----
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/a/test'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/b/0.2'),  # <----
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/b/test'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/c/0.2'),  # <----
 WindowsPath('C:/Temp/aaa/c/test')]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а можно через input("Found folders 0.1, enter new name: ")

Comment: @IgorK, можно: `new = input("Found folders 0.1, enter new name: ")` и дальше используйте `new` вместо `'0.2'`